# Jenkins- Post Build Task: access the parameterized value of the job

Tags: jenkins

I have Job on Jenkins ver. 1.500 with build ID parameterized. 
I want to use this parameterized value in the subject line of section "Post-build Actions".

If I try to access using $ID or ${ID} its printing it as plane string "$ID"[without value substitution]. I am aware of environmental variable $BUILD_NUMBER, which is giving the current job #number.

Can someone share, how to achieve this simple task of reading build number?

$PROJECT_NAME -  Job # $ID built at $BUILD_ID - $BUILD_STATUS!

--Thanks,Prashant

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about "Editable Email Notification", please confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about **[Editable Email Notification](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** post-build action. It has it's own way of referencing variables.

Variables that are available within the plugin, can be referenced directly as `${VARIABLE}`, in both the *body* of the email and the *subject line*. For a list of available variables, click on the `?` icon for on-page help.

However to access other **environmental** variables, including the parameters used by the build, you have to use the format `${ENV, var="VARIABLE"}`, so in your case, it would be `${ENV, var="ID"}`

Comment: Thanks Slav...${ENV, var="ID"} did trick for me..Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Slav how we can pass all the parametre in the body of email ?